# Troubleshooting Duplication of Controller request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for some help with an issue I've noticed with a couple of actions in my app. The problem isn't consistent, happens maybe 50% of the time. To me, it looks like the route is being called twice in the same second:

```
Started POST "/profile/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-29 15:36:09 -0800
Started POST "/profile/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-29 15:36:09 -0800
Processing by ProfileController#sign_in as JS
Processing by ProfileController#sign_in as JS
```

...(The logging goes on to show duplication of every controller/action/logging.)

Any ideas/suggestions on where I could potentially look? 
The inconsistency of the error happening leads me to think it's something peculiar, maybe app/db setup related? Initially I thought the path may have been getting called twice somewhere, but I can see it's not from a project search.

I can't really think of a way of narrowing the search as all statements are duplicated and end in a Database error leading to a 500 error (as 2 dupe updates attempt to run).

Any tips/tricks to investigate that anyone can offer?

Thanks.

Comment: Given that those calls are JS, I guess you have some js that's getting loaded twice in the browser. Could be multiple reasons for that.

Comment: A very common reason for requests like this are users that double click on links or buttons. It feels to me like opening programms with double-clinks trained pleople to double-click everywhere. Depending on your application this can lead to very interesting race-conditions too.